# dynamic generated svg to be sent via email

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, svg

I am new to SVG, and I have an online web form which contains an dynamic svg. The form allows users to change the svg's appearance including colours etc. What I want to do is have the svg included in an email (along with other user form input such as name, address etc (i have done the user input part).

I was wondering if anyone could give me guidance as to the best method for adding a representation of the svg into the email. Should I convert the svg first to a jpeg or png and attach this to the email?

I don't have an actual .svg file but instead the svg is generated within the `<svg></svg>` tags.

Comment: Did you tried to add the svg url at the src parameter of an image?